# Communication Between Windows and web application using vb.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am new for dotnet. i need to implement one concept that is i am developing one desktop application that is act as server and create one website. so client give a request from website to my desktop application. the server get the request and perform some task and then response to client. how to implement this concept. whether i use Http Listener or any other concept available in dotnet.

the sample request and response examples

Client Request: http://ipaddress/ConnectionStatus/

Server Response: ALIVE

Client Request: http://ipaddress/MARSrequest/?userid=1010"

Server Response: username=bala balance=1000

how can i implement this concept.

Comment: This is, unless I'm reading it wrong, the definition of a WCF service.  I'd suggest googling "hosting a WCF Service in a Winforms application" and following the instructions on the first Microsoft article that comes up.  On second thought, I googled it for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx

Comment: First, pick a language; C# or VB.NET. Then, find some tutorials on the language you choose. Learn about the various networking libraries available. Come back when you have started working on some code, and have some specific problem to ask us about.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# language then this will helps you....

A simple web service outta do the trick.  Just create a service in ASP.NET and add it as a reference to your desktop application.  There's no need to go overkill to accomplish such a simple task.

You could use WCF or Remoting or Sockets -- by why waste time when the learning curve is so much higher?  Creating a web service will take no time at all and should give you all the functionality you need.

Here's a brief walkthrough to get you up and running.

1. In Visual Studio, create a new web site and select ASP.NET Web Service.
2. A stub method will be created called HelloWorld e.g.

   ```
     [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {      
        return "Hello World";

    }
   ```
3. Run your site.
4. Go to your desktop application.
5. Under your solution explorer, right click on the project and click Add Web Reference
6. Enter the URL of where you have your web service running and click Go**
7. Once your reference is found, rename it to something meaningful and click Add Reference.
8. You can now access the methods exposed by your web service as if they are local objects.  You should be able to now see the HelloWorld method exposed by the service.

** Remember, in order for you to have a web reference with a static URL, you'll need to host the reference in IIS.  When Visual Studio runs your service from the IDE, it will create a temporary URL and port, which WILL change on future runs.  This is simply to show you how simple working with web services are.

You can add your own methods and return types in the same class as the HelloWorld method, by adding the [WebMethod] flag above your methods.  If you change something in your service, go back to your desktop application, right click on the service, and click Update.